# column selection and row filtering in one step

Tags: python, pandas

How do you do

column selection:

```
df[['A', 'C', 'D']]
```

and

row filtering:

```
df[df['C'] > 5]
```

in one step?

I tried

```
df[df[['A', 'C', 'D']]['C'] > 5]
```

but it did just the row filtering and brought back the columns I was trying to lose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `.loc` and assign it back

```
df1=df.loc[df.C>5,['A','B','C']]
```